# How to configure c3p0 in hibernate to auto-refresh stale DB connections

Tags: oracle, hibernate, c3p0

I am using hibernate 3, c3p0 9.1.2, Oracle 11g in my application. If I restart the Oracle then the stale connections are not getting refresh and I am getting exception "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection". Below is my hibernate.cfg.xml.

I am a beginner in Hibernate API. Can you please suggest how to configure hibernate to automatically refresh the stale connections on a specified time.

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ems
        emsman

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property> <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>

    <property name="c3p0.validate">true</property>

<mapping resource="<package-name>/GroupOpWorkflow.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="<package-name>/GroupOperation.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="<package-name>/GroupOpNode.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="<package-name>/NodeStatusLog.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's `c3p0`, your database connection pool, that you need to configure - not hibernate.  Try setting `idleConnectionTestPeriod` and an appropriate `preferredTestQuery`, e.g., `select 1 from dual`.  The `validate` property has been deprecated and it's recommended that you not use that.

See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool for more information.  You'll get the most control if you create a `c3p0.properties` file in `WEB-INF/classes` but you need to make sure not to override those properties in your `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Lee. Can I give c3p0.properties file path as java System Properties or loading the properties during start-up of application. Will hibernate override the c3p0.properties properties?

Comment: hibernate overrides the c3p0.properties I believe.  You don't need to manually load the c3p0.properties file, just make sure it's visible at the right place and it'll configure itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
After gone through the document { http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool } I found C3P0 was not a all used by hibernate. 

So wrote a new C3P0 xml file and used the below system properties:

C3P0_SYS_PROPS="-Dcom.mchange.v2.c3p0.cfg.xml=<FILE-PATH>/c3p0-config.xml -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog -Dcom.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog.DE
FAULT_CUTOFF_LEVEL=WARNING"


So here is the final working configuration


hibernate.cfg.xml 


 <session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ems</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">emsman</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property> <!-- In seconds -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
.....


<c3p0-config>
<default-config>
<!-- Configuring Connection     Testing -->
<!-- property name="automaticTestTable">TEST_EMS_HIBERNATE_CONN</property -->
<property name="checkoutTimeout">0</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">false</property>
<property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 from dual</property>
<!-- Configuring Recovery From Database Outages -->
<property name="acquireRetryAttempts">0</property>
<property name="acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
<property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure">false</property>
<!-- Configuring to     Debug and Workaround Broken     Client Apps     -->
<property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">1800</property>
<property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
</default-config>


c3p0-config.xml


<c3p0-config>
<default-config>
<!-- Configuring Connection     Testing -->
<!-- property name="automaticTestTable">TEST_EMS_HIBERNATE_CONN</property -->
<property name="checkoutTimeout">0</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
<property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">false</property>
<property name="preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 from dual</property>
<!-- Configuring Recovery From Database Outages -->
<property name="acquireRetryAttempts">0</property>
<property name="acquireRetryDelay">1000</property>
<property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure">false</property>
<!-- Configuring to     Debug and Workaround Broken     Client Apps     -->
<property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout">1800</property>
<property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces">true</property>
</default-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, it's a **simple advice** from the *author* of c3p0 taken [here](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing):

> The best thing to do is usually to try Step 3, see if it helps
> (however you measure performance), see if it hurts (is your
> application troubled by broken Connections? does it recover from
> database restarts well enough?), and then decide.
>
> Step 3:
>  If you'd like to improve performance by eliminating
> Connection testing from clients' code path:
>
> Set testConnectionOnCheckout to false
>
> Set testConnectionOnCheckin to true
>
> Set idleConnectionTestPeriod to 30, fire up you application and
> observe. This is a pretty robust setting, all Connections will tested
> on check-in and every 30 seconds thereafter while in the pool. Your
> application should experience broken or stale Connections only very
> rarely, and the pool should recover from a database shutdown and
> restart quickly. But there is some overhead associated with all that
> Connection testing.
>
> If database restarts will be rare so quick recovery is not an issue,
> consider reducing the frequency of tests by idleConnectionTestPeriod
> to, say, 300, and see whether clients are troubled by stale or broken
> Connections. If not, stick with 300, or try an even bigger number.
> Consider setting testConnectionOnCheckin back to false to avoid
> unnecessary tests on checkin. Alternatively, if your application does
> encounter bad Connections, consider reducing idleConnectionTestPeriod
> and set testConnectionOnCheckin back to true. There are no correct or
> incorrect values for these parameters: you are trading off overhead
> for reliability in deciding how frequently to test. The exact numbers
> are not so critical. It's usually easy to find configurations that
> perform well. It's rarely worth spending time in pursuit of "optimal"
> values here.