# AWS RDS with Elastic Beanstalk and Tomcat - "The last packet successfully received from the server was ___ seconds ago"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Thank you for any insight you're able to provide. I'm new to system administration and have caught myself in a corner.

I have an RDS instance with Amazon Web Services. It's hosting a MySQL 5.6 database. My Elastic Beanstalk application is running a Linux server with Tomcat 8/Java 8. My web application uses Hibernate to communicate with the database. In my Hibernate.cfg.xml file, I have added "autoReconnect=true" to my database link but this has not helped.

Does anyone recognize this error, and can give me an idea of what may be causing it?

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:981)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)
    com.grandcircus.spring.util.dao.ChaplainDAO.getByEmail(ChaplainDAO.java:32)
    com.grandcircus.spring.util.dao.DAO.getUserType(DAO.java:68)
    com.grandcircus.spring.controller.HomeController.loginFormSubmit(HomeController.java:89)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was273873 seconds ago.The last packet sent successfully to the server was 273873 seconds ago, which  is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3246)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1917)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)
    com.grandcircus.spring.util.dao.ChaplainDAO.getByEmail(ChaplainDAO.java:32)
    com.grandcircus.spring.util.dao.DAO.getUserType(DAO.java:68)
    com.grandcircus.spring.controller.HomeController.loginFormSubmit(HomeController.java:89)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
    java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3227)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1917)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:369)
    com.grandcircus.spring.util.dao.ChaplainDAO.getByEmail(ChaplainDAO.java:32)
    com.grandcircus.spring.util.dao.DAO.getUserType(DAO.java:68)
    com.grandcircus.spring.controller.HomeController.loginFormSubmit(HomeController.java:89)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:871)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

As Deepak suggested, this was a connection pooling issue. I followed the steps provided my MKYong on the subject, and this corrected the issue. Read more here:

https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/

Comment: According to the error, you're trying to use a connection that was established with the database at one point, but has been completely unused and idle for over 3 days. (!?)  So... was it over 3 days before this message occurred that you added `&autoReconnect=true`?  Or is it possible that your service was not restarted when the change was made?

Comment: Currently, the timer starts when I restart my elastic beanstalk servers, instead of reconnecting when I visit the elastic beanstalk application's website. So, I restarted my server a little over three days ago, and it timed out from there. I've had autoReconnect=true in my project from the beginning.

Comment: That makes sense.  I think the answer below has correctly assessed that this isn't really an issue specific to AWS, RDS, or EB, but your connection pool isn't properly maintaining its pooled connections and is giving you a less-than-helpful error.  Possibly useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html

Comment: Spot on! I'm going to check it out, and then wait to see if the error reappears. I'll check back here in about 6+ hours.

Comment: See you in [28800 seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout).  Feel free to post your findings as an answer (assuming it works), since you're the one doing the real work, here.

Comment: It worked! I've updated my OP to show what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with AWS or RDS or beanstalk. This is a typical connection pool issue.

To make sure if this is pool issue; try restarting your tomcat.. This problem should go away. If yes, try to google for that issue; you will find lots of help something like [How to configure c3p0 in hibernate to auto-refresh stale DB connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288946/how-to-configure-c3p0-in-hibernate-to-auto-refresh-stale-db-connections)

Comment: Thank you Deepak! I'm going to give this a shot, and see if this is the solution. As it takes some time for the message to reappear, I'll be checking the site periodically, and will check back here in a few hours to vote+ if that solved it. Thank you again!

Comment: This solved the issue. I'm sitting at 7 and a half hours after restarting my servers, and the site is still working. Thank you Deepak!