# JPA EntityManager reject to work after database restart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have **Spring Boot Application** and I am using **JPA EntityManager**.

I **run** **db** and my application. While my **application is running I stop and start my database.**

After this actions, my application **works like db is still stopped**.

It always says that **transaction is failed**.

I must **restart** application to make it work. **How to solve it?**

**UPDATE: Connection pool configuration**

```
@Bean("dataSource")
    @Singleton
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("url"));
        basicDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("user"));
        basicDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("password"));
        basicDataSource.setInitialSize(5);
        basicDataSource.setMinIdle(3);
        basicDataSource.setMaxIdle(15);
        basicDataSource.setMaxWait(10000);
        basicDataSource.setMaxActive(100);
        return basicDataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Do you use any connection pool or JNDI?
Are there any database failover clustering?

Comment: Yes, I configure connectionPool in @Configuration.

Comment: It's my first RESTful application, I don't care about specific connection pool, but my application have 2 Dao - the first works with DataSource + JDBC, the second with JPA. And when I configure connection pool, spring boot make jpa use this connection pool i think

Comment: Use Spring auto configuration let spring manage the connections. See if it helps.

Comment: @MillerCyChan your question was amazing. I change connectionPool to c3p0 and now it works well, thank you!

Comment: @sankar I know JPA use his own connection pool. But as I know I can't take his connection pool and use outside it

Comment: Apart from c3p0, you may use JNDI to reference a data source in app server such as wildfly, weblogic or websphere. The data source can be XA with clustering.

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288946/how-to-configure-c3p0-in-hibernate-to-auto-refresh-stale-db-connections